# Android: Time Loop in milliseconds

Tags: android, android-activity, time

This game is similar to one of those where your try to survive for as long as possible, like those hell-shooter games.

So basically I wish to record to amount of time the user can survive after pressing "start". Similarly, I would like to continue to update the frames at that time. I am thinking about using Handler or Timer or Animation for updating frames (the activity) and mathematically manipulating SimpleDateFormat. However, I'm not too sure how one would go about it.

As a start, I would like to have something like that of the FruitNinja Survival mode, though with smaller times recorded too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use timer or thread handler

```
   timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

               Do your own code
                ///////schedule the timer, after the first 100ms the TimerTask will run every 1000ms
            }
        }, 1000, 1000);
```

Can Use Another handler

```
  Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(
            new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    afficher();
                }
            }, 1000L);
```